# Zip multiple pdf into a single file zip file using Java

Tags: java, pdf, zip

I'm able to generate a pdf and flush it to the browser. But, now my requirement is changed. I need to generate multiple pdf and keep them in a single zip file and flush it to the browser. I followed this http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-from-a-set-of-files.html

But could not find how to integrate in my code. Here is my code. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
            byte[] documentBytes =  TSService.generateDocument(dealKey, i);
            String documentType = TSUtil.getDocumentType(i);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+documentType);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, postcheck=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.setContentLength(documentBytes.length); 
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(documentBytes);       
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
```

Initially I had only code which is in loop. Now, I want to generate 5 reports based on i value.

Updated code for Alex

```
String documentType = TSUtil.getDocumentType(Integer.valueOf(documentKey));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=dd.zip");
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, postcheck=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            byte[] documentBytes =  TSService.generateDocument(dealKey, i);
            ZipEntry zip = new ZipEntry(i+".pdf");
            zout.putNextEntry(zip);
            zout.write(documentBytes);
            zout.closeEntry();
        }

        zout.close();
```

Comment: You have to use a ZipOutputStream, flush all the pdf in this outpustream then flush the result in the browser

Comment: @Tuco, can you plz post a sample snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code should be worked and can be directly downloaded without creating any temp files. All are created on the fly and are on memory.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+***Your zip filename***);
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, postcheck=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);

for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    byte[] documentBytes =  TSService.generateDocument(dealKey, i);
    ZipEntry zip = new ZipEntry(***your pdf name***);
    zout.putNextEntry(zip);
    zout.write(documentBytes);
    zout.closeEntry();
}

zout.close();
```

**UPDATED**

I have just tried the below code and without problem. A new zip file can be created with 5 text files inside. So I have no idea why you get exceptions.

```
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("abc.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
        byte[] documentBytes =  "12345".getBytes();
        ZipEntry zip = new ZipEntry(i+".txt");
        zout.putNextEntry(zip);
        zout.write(documentBytes);
        zout.closeEntry();
    }

    zout.close();
```

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: it gave exception immediately after  ZipEntry zip = new ZipEntry("dd.zip"); as java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: dd.zip

Comment: ZipEntry is used for your PDF filename. So you may name your 1st file as 1.pdf and the 2nd as 2.pdf and so on.

Comment: I tried the same, but still. I will update my latest code.  Please check it

Answer (score 1):

I had done same task with xml file.below is my code

```
public String createZipFromXmlFile(List<String> filePath) {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMddHHmmssSS").format(new Date());
    String fName = "zipDownload" + date + ".zip";
    System.out.println(" File Path.................."+filePath);
    String fileName = filePath.get(0).substring(0, filePath.get(0).indexOf("xml")) + "//" + fName;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
        for (String fnm : filePath) {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(fnm));
            ZipEntry zip = new ZipEntry(fnm.substring(fnm.indexOf("xml")));
            zout.putNextEntry(zip);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fin.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zout.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            zout.closeEntry();
            fin.close();
        }
        zout.close();
        fout.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

where filePath is list that contains path of xml files.

Comment: I will not have file path. The file will not be stored initially. I want to generate a zip folder with the pdf which is generated from the response.

Comment: You should keep the path of pdf file into list and pass into above method.my xml files also created at runtime.i store them into project local path and then get list of paths.

Comment: File path will look for the file which is stored right?

Comment: I think you may use `ByteArrayInputStream` instead of `FileInputStream` in your case.

Comment: File path for that pdf which is created by response.

Comment: @Alex, can you please provide any snippet which can be used in my case

Comment: Replace that `FileInputStream` line with this: `ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(documentBytes)`

Comment: @AlokSingh, sorry, the files are be directly downloaded into downloads as of now.

Comment: You should create a list of string type and store path of pdf file(like u mention above) and at end of your pdf generate method call this method with your list.

Comment: @AlokSingh, the files are directly downloaded till now. But, you are saying to mention the file path. How should I mention before saving itself

Comment: @Yakhoob, You should save into any temp location then use this code.

Comment: No, you should not save anything into a temporary location. That's a bad, inefficient and unnecessary step.

Comment: @AlokSingh, why should I store in temp? I want to flush at once all these files in a zip folder