# Send different types of objects using Java in single call

Tags: java

First of all, I'm not sure whether this could be possible or not. I'm flushing bytes of data as PDF to the browser. Now the requirement is, I want to generate the pdf and also send one more extra object to be sent . Is it possible?

I've written something like this, but the result object is not getting as response.

```
YBUtil.GeneratePdf(response,documentBytes, "Bureau"); 
result.setStatus("SUCCESS");
return result; --> I want to pass this object as well
```

### GeneratePdf method

```
    public static void GeneratePdf(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] documentBytes, String fileName){

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+fileName+".pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, postcheck=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setContentLength(documentBytes.length); 
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(documentBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: how about zip them? -> [Zip multiple pdf into a single file zip file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560710/zip-multiple-pdf-into-a-single-file-zip-file-using-java)

Comment: @fantaghirocco, what do you mean? I want result object and pdf to be sent back to browser at the same time

Comment: Where do you want that extra response?

Comment: why isn't HTTP 200 OK  enough? http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html? If you want an extra response, use a web service

Comment: I want to send that response back to my Ajax call (Result object will hold some values)

Comment: @fantaghirocco, my result object will hold some values that should be parsed on the client as well as pdf should be displayed

Comment: @Yakhoob I'm just curious. Couldn't you add that extra response to a session and extract it from there?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, this is more about the HTTP protocol than about Java.

HTTP is designed to send requests, with one optional request body sent along, and to receive a response in reaction, with one optional response body sent along. One. Not more than that.

When dealing with typical text stuff, you can send/respond a text-like format such as XML, JSON or web forms, that contain all the stuff you want it to contain. But when you want to receive/send a file, it's binary stuff and it must be sent as-is, alongside metadata that tell the file's type and name.

Now when you want to send/receive *more* than just a file, it looks like you're stuck. Well no. Look up multipart/form-data and realize you can use something similar for an HTTP response. Just like an email would.

Java can be programmed to respond with a multipart response. However, it is a bit of work to program, and I haven't really found an effective library that will success in helping me do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by sending a DTO object that will contain bytes(for pdf, this parsing of pdf is done on client side) and other values added to the DTO which are necessary.